# How does one access model data in a router/controller?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Bear with me please, I'm new.

Been breaking my head over this problem and sort of here as last resort. It's about how to access a model's data when that route loads. For instance, when /meals/2 loads, I want a function to run that sets the background of the document using that model's background-image string property. Or when /meals loads, the a function that uses a property of the collection's first item.

Any help on 'the ember way' to do this would be much appreciated.

Menu.hbs

```
  {{#each meal in model}}
    <span {{action 'mealSelected' meal.image_large}}>
      {{#link-to 'menu.meal' meal tagName="li" class="meal-block" href="view.href"}}
        [...]
      {{/link-to}}
    </span>
  {{/each}}

<div id="meal-info-wrapper">

  {{outlet}}

</div>
```

Model:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  image: DS.attr('string')
});
```

Router.js

```
export default Router.map(function() {
    this.route('about');
    this.route('menu', { path: '/' }, function() {
        this.route('meal', { path: '/meal/:id/:slug' });
    });
});
```

routes/menu.js

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('menu');
  },
  afterModel: function() {
    Ember.$(document).anystretch('temp-images/bg-1.png');
  }
});
```

What I want to do in routes/menu.js for instance would be to have that image url be supplied by the model.

Comment: Post ur relevant code.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Added some code. Hope it's helpful in understanding the problem.

Comment: afterModel already gets the resolved model passed in. Here is a demo http://emberjs.jsbin.com/peguvu/2/edit?html,js,console,output But @givanse is right, DOM manipulation should not happen in a route. Do it with a component. http://emberjs.jsbin.com/peguvu/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`afterModel` will run only once the model has been resolved, and the model is passed as an argument. So, based on my understanding of your app, you can adjust your `routes/menu` example to:

```
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('menu');
  },
  afterModel: function(model) {
    Ember.$(document).anystretch(model.get('firstObject.image'));
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I misunderstood something, what you want to do is:

> Change the background image of a DOM element based on a property found
>   in each Model's record.

1. Model loading is an async operation, you want to do the image swaping once you are sure the data is loaded. You used the `afterModel` hook to guarantee that, but that is not enough.
2. You want to modify the DOM inside your template, but you need to make sure that the template has been rendered. So, the DOM manipulation logic, instead of placing it in `afterModel`, it belongs to the `didInsertElement` event that Views have.

I suggest you use a component (its a view too), something like:

```
  // your template
  {{#each meal in model}}
    {{meal-component content=meal}}
  {{/each}}

  // the meal-component
  didInsertElement: function() {
     var imgURLProperty = this.get('content.imgURLProperty');
     Ember.$(document).anystretch(imgURLProperty);
  }
```

Of course, you can't copy paste any of that. It just shows you the main mechanic of how you can modify a template based on the properties of a model.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems like components is the way to go. Not sure what the protocol for accepting correct answers is on StackOverflow. Technically Luke's answer is exactly what the question asks, so I've marked his as accepted answer.